# Creating Stripe transfers at the same time as creating Payment intent

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe and am trying to implement the scenario described here
[image]

The frontend is making a call to the backend that has this code

```
var service = new PaymentIntentService();
var createOptions = new PaymentIntentCreateOptions
{
    PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string>
        {
        "card",
        },
    Amount = (long?)(payment.Amount * 100),
    Currency = "EUR"
};
var result = await service.CreateAsync(createOptions);
return result.ClientSecret
```

In the documentation it says that the below code should be run "later" but it doesn't specify when. In my case I would prefer submitting the transfers to Stripe as soon as possible and preferably connecting them to the above payment so the transfers would be automatically handled by Stripe when the payment is done.

As I read the documentation (https://stripe.com/docs/api/transfers/create#create_transfer-source_transaction) SourceTransaction could be used for this.

```
var transferService = new TransferService();

var transfer1Options = new TransferCreateOptions
{
    Amount = 100,
    Currency = "eur",
    Destination = "{{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}}",
    SourceTransaction = result.Id
};

var transfer1 = transferService.Create(transfer1Options);
```

The result -variable contains a Charges -list but that is empty and when doing the above, i.e. adding the payment intent's id to SourceTransaction property, I get an error that the charge does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

> In the documentation it says that the below code should be run "later" but it doesn't specify when

It's whenever you are ready to make the transfer, after the payment has succeeded, essentially.

> As I read the documentation (https://stripe.com/docs/api/transfers/create#create_transfer-source_transaction) SourceTransaction could be used for this.

Yep, you should definitely use `source_transaction` here! Otherwise the transfers won't succeed since the funds would not be available yet.

> The result -variable contains a Charges -list but that is empty and when doing the above, i.e. adding the payment intent's id to SourceTransaction property, I get an error that the charge does not exist.

The value to pass to `source_transaction` is indeed the `intent.charges.data[0].id` , of a PaymentIntent that has succeeded and has a Charge.

You don't have a Charge ID because you *haven't actually processed a payment yet*. Creating a PaymentIntent doesn't process a payment.

You have to do the normal full PaymentIntent integration by building a form that collects payment details and 'confirms' the PaymentIntent, that's the action that processes the payment, and after that succeeds, the `charges` array will have a Charge in it that can be used for the transfer. For example you might create the transfer as part of handling the `payment_intent.payment_succeeded` webhook event.

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Thanks a lot, putting the intent.charges.data[0].id in the source_transaction was the solution for me!